# Error on posting on behalf of a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-permissions

I have an app that programmatically make post on a configured Facebook Page.
My app obviously have both the manage_pages and publish_pages permissions approved and I'm using pages access token
[image: Screenshot of the App Review section from Facebook dashboard]

Everything work well since now, but recently when I POST on page feed

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/234002440799692/feed
```

I get this error:

```
{"error": {
   "message":"(#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
   "type":"OAuthException",
   "code":200,
   "fbtrace_id":"HEVcI\/Tq3fW"
}}
```

I know that Facebook has deprecated publish_actions scope, so that it's not possible anymore to post programmatically on the personal feed, but I can't find out why the post on a page return this kind of error.
Some further infos:

- posting with a developer account actually work
- the user by which the page access token is obtained, created the page on Facebook (so I think it's an admin for the page)
- i recently migrated from graph_api v2.12 to v.3.1

Any suggestion will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out what the problem with some pages is.
It seem that now, if the user grant the manage_pages and publish_pages permission, that will be valid only for already existing pages!

New pages haven't the permission granted by default.

The only way I can fix the problem was to remove my app from the user profile (Facebook Settings > Business Integrations > Select the app > Remove) and then prompt the user again with the Facebook OAuth permission dialog.

I don't know if there is a way to force the app removal programmatically, but I can't find out.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/234002440799692/feed?&access_token={access_token}
```